# Creating Django´s blog Post custom fields

Tags: python, django, anaconda, blogs

I am new to django, I am trying to add custom fields to the regular django blog Post App.

This is the blog fields out of the box:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I need to create 4 fields:

- Types (charfield length=200)
- Status of item (combobox with **OK** and **NOK** options)
- Ranking (numbers, 1-10)
- Deployed (charfield length=200)

I have tried simply adding those fields to my models.py below but it breaks the website:

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
Types = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
etc
```

Error on my anaconda prompt:
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Where else do I need to add the fields? DO I need to create a separate class? If so, how do I add to the create post backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you indent in python, python just expects that indentation in first line should be the same as indentation in rest of the lines, be it 4 spaces, 1 space, 1 tab, or whatever.

As it is suggested in [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), we should use "Spaces" rather than using "Tabs"! Anyway, the error says you probably added those new fields with inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (i.e. probably you are using tabs instead of 4 spaces)

Comment: This is correct, I did use 4 spaces and it doesn´t break the site anymore, I am getting a database error on the frontend of my site: OperationalError at /
no such column: blog_post.tipo
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http:XXXXX
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: blog_post.tipo
Exception Location: \conda\conda\envs\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 383

Comment: Have you tried these commands: `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` ? Anyway, this is a different question. I suggest close this question and start over to follow new problems

Comment: this is it, @aminrd. A rookie mistake here... well, that is the only way to learn! Please write it as an answer so I can properly award you.

Comment: You can find your answer in this link: https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-add-new-model-field-to-exist-django-model/

Comment: For new fields, you should have a default value if you want to keep your current database before executing `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly as it says. Remember Python does not use curly brackets, it uses indentations. You have to make sure your lines are properly indented. I don't know the editor you are using but you can check whether there are formatting plugins or extensions for it. A quick solution though is to just delete all the white spaces then indent with the tab. Indentation is done via the tab key and not the space key.